# What is the difference between CAST(... to STRING) and BASE64(...)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When converting from VARBINARY to STRING, I am wondering if the operations CAST(... to STRING) and BASE64(...) in Spark sql are interchangeable. If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are (totally) different, when casting binary to string Spark interprets the bytes as *UTF-8* encoded data while as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encodes bytes to text using [some common printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table). For example, casting byte 33 to UTF-8 string would produce string `"!"` as unicode point 33 is exclamation mark.

```
val df = Seq(Array[Byte](33)).toDF("test")
df.select($"test".cast(StringType)).show()
```

```
+----+
|test|
+----+
|   !|
+----+
```

and base64:

```
df.select(base64($"test")).show()
```

```
+------------+
|base64(test)|
+------------+
|        IQ==|
+------------+
```

Note that casting bytes to string assumes UTF-8 encoding, so

```
val df = Seq("foo".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
             "foo".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)).toDF("test")

df.select($"test".cast(StringType)).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+
|    test|
+--------+
|     foo|
|���f�o�o   |
+--------+
```